# navigating hierarchy of xml input file

Tags: java, xml

How do I list the element names at a given level in an xml schema hierarchy?  The code I have below is listing all element names at every level of the hierarchy, with no concept of nesting.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CDA.xsl"?>
<SomeDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:something">
<title>some title</title>
<languageCode code="en-US"/>
<versionNumber value="1"/>
<recordTarget>
    <someRole>
        <id extension="998991"/>
        <addr use="HP">
            <streetAddressLine>1357 Amber Drive</streetAddressLine>
            <city>Beaverton</city>
            <state>OR</state>
            <postalCode>97867</postalCode>
            <country>US</country>
        </addr>
        <telecom value="tel:(816)276-6909" use="HP"/>
    </someRole>
</recordTarget>
</SomeDocument>
```

Here is my java method for importing and iterating the xml file:

```
public static void parseFile() {
    //get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        //Using factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
        Document dom = db.parse("D:\\mypath\\somefile.xml");
        //get the root element
        Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
        //get a nodelist of elements
        NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("*");
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nl.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    System.out.println("node.getNodeName() is: "+node.getNodeName());
                }

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
title
languageCode
versionNumber
recordTarget
someRole
id
addr
streetAddressLine
city
state
postalCode
country
telecom
```

Instead, I would like to output the following:

```
title
languageCode
versionNumber
recordTarget
```

It would be nice to then be able to list the children of `recordTarget` as `someRole`, and then to list the children of `someRole` as `id`, `addr`, and `telecom`.  And so on, but at my discretion in the code.  How can I change my code to get the output that I want?

Comment: Did you consider using JAXB? A DOM tree with its low-level API isn't fun to work with.

Comment: @laune Thank you for the suggestion.  My application's entity model does not map directly to the xml schema. Does JAXB require an obvious mapping from xml to object names and properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all nodes with this line:

```
NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Change it to

```
NodeList nl = docEle.getChildNodes();
```

to get all of its children.  Your print statement will then give you the output you're looking for.

Then, when you iterate through your NodeList, you can choose to call the same method on each Node you create:

```
NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
```

If you want to print an XML-like structure, perhaps a recursive method that prints all child nodes is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-write the `parseFile` (I'd rather call it `parseChildrenElementNames`) method to take an input `String` that specifies the element name for which you want to print out its children element names:

```
public static void parseChildrenElementNames(String parentElementName) {
    // get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        // Using factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        // parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
        Document dom = db
                .parse("D:\\mypath\\somefile.xml");
        // get the root element
        NodeList elementsByTagName = dom.getElementsByTagName(parentElementName);
        if(elementsByTagName != null) {
            Node parentElement = elementsByTagName.item(0);
            // get a nodelist of elements
            NodeList nl = parentElement.getChildNodes();
            if (nl != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nl.item(i);
                    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        System.out.println("node.getNodeName() is: "
                                + node.getNodeName());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, this will only consider the first element that matches the specified name.

For example, to get the list of elements under the first node named `someRole`, you would call `parseChildrenElementNames("someRole");` which would print out:

```
node.getNodeName() is: id
node.getNodeName() is: addr
node.getNodeName() is: telecom
```